# how do i fix my netbeans categories and running issue?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

hello everyone i am having a trouble with my netbeans 8.2 it isn't showing me the regular categories when i click on new project or file, also it doesn't run i have tried to delete jdk 8 and reinstall it multiple times but it just does not work the other solution was to edit netbeans package content notes with the jdk path but still nothing changed

[image: below there is a screenshot of my screen]

Answer (score 0):

update: i fixed it by these steps
1.open netbeans
2.press on tools>plugins> installed
3.activate all the plugins by selecting them from the left column
[image: a screenshot to demonstrate]

:)